# MATLAB in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, matlab, kalman-filter

Is there any way I can represent at least this much MATLAB code in android/java - 
[a,b,c]=xlsread('../Data/dataset.xls');

a = [1 dt; 0 1]; % transition matrix

y=[data(t+1,1);data(t+1,vel_p_noise^2)];

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that if you can convert `xls` to `csv` and then use this https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html

Comment: Thanks for that. But, how do I achieve this - y=[data(t+1,1);data(t+1,vel_p_noise^2)];

Comment: I do not see a reason why not. It will not be as short and easy as the MATLAB code but I am sure you can achieve the same results in java :)

Comment: If this is a Kalman Filter, why not use something like [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/filter/KalmanFilter.html)? Even if not - I'm sure there are open source java implementation of other filters as well. P.S. I would also tag the question with the type of filter you're implementing.

Comment: Thanks a ton Dev,.. I wanted the same! Kalman filter, in a slightly modified way.